Apache POI Pivot Field Settings Subtotal to None
I'd like to use the Apache POI API to manipulate the Field Settings of a pivot table field by setting the Subtotals to None in the Subtotals & Filters tab of the settings (see attached screenshot, circled in red)
This does not work: Accessing Field Settings of Pivot Table using Apache POI

